# Can't set Foreground color in DataGrid using Binding

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working with a DataGrid in a Windows UWP application.

I'm trying to set the Foreground property of a DataGridTextColumn by binding it to a color value in my model. My model object has a property, called Color, that returns a value of type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush. As this is the same type as the Foreground property, I assumed I could set it directly, like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" ...
```

However, this results in a runtime exception that says, "Failed to assign property".

I have seen code samples that appear to be doing the same thing, and I'm struggling to understand why this won't work.

Comment: Please post all code used for binding.

Comment: Looking at the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush?view=winrt-19041) it seems to only accept strings in xaml

Comment: Are you saying that the Foreground property is expecting a string? What would I put in this string?

Comment: I tried using string values such as "Red" or "Blue". I get the same error. These values do work if I type them literally into the xaml file, but not with Binding.

Comment: I also tried using a Converter; same error and my converter code never even gets called. This is very confusing. I have used converters elsewhere to set colors without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview#binding-sources-binding-targets-the-role-of-frameworkelement), we know that a property must be a dependency property to be the target of a **{Binding}** markup extension, but **{x:Bind}** does not have this requirement as it uses generated code to apply its binding values. From the [code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridTextColumn.cs#L135) of `Foreground` of  `DataGridTextColumn`, the `Foreground` property is not a dependency property, therefore it is not supported to do the data binding by `{Binding}` extension for the `Foreground` property.

You could custom a `CellTemplate` to set a data binding for the `Foreground` property for a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#datagridtemplatecolumn) instance.

For example:

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="header">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">
                <StackPanel >
                //MyBrush is a SolidColorBrush in Customer class, adjust it for your scenario
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" Foreground="{x:Bind MyBrush}"/>  
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up for me. I managed to get what I wanted using a variation of your example, but it's a lot of work to do this for each cell, so I'll likely just live without it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this issue is still vexing me.

I thought I had managed to set the row color dynamically, but it turns out that the dynamic color I chose was the same as the default color, and when I changed it, nothing happened.

So I'm still looking for a solution.

I have a lot of columns. It would not be feasible for me to implement a solution that required pasting 10+ lines of XML dozens of times.

Isn't there some way to do this in code? Can I just grab the UI element containing the text somehow, and modify it?

Here is an example of what I am doing. The TextWrapping and TextAlignment settings work, but the Foreground setting doesn't work, even if I assign it a constant value.

```
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="notesCol" Binding="{Binding Notes, Mode=OneWay}" MaxWidth="500" Header="Notes" Tag="Notes">
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```